How to prevent my character from sliding?
My character slides whenever they move and I dont want them sliding at all. 
I've tried setting the friction high to fix it but that didn't work. I tried to code it so it stops sliding but that didn't work. What might be the reason of that?
My code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementSteamDeck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius = 0.1f;
    public float coyoteTime = 0.2f;
    private float coyoteTimeCounter;

    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool jumpHeld;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
 
    void Update()
     {
        Move();
 
        jumpHeld = Input.GetButton("Jump"); // A button for jumping on Steam Deck
 
         UpdateAnimations();
     }

    void FixedUpdate()
     {
        if (jumpHeld && (isGrounded || coyoteTimeCounter > 0))
          {
             Jump();
         }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        // Detect joystick input for Steam Deck
        float moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // Check if both A and D keys or both Left and Right arrow keys are pressed
        bool aPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
        bool dPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
        bool leftArrowPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
        bool rightArrowPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);

        if ((aPressed && dPressed) || (leftArrowPressed && rightArrowPressed))
        {
            moveInput = 0; // Prevent movement if both keys are pressed
        }
         else if (aPressed || leftArrowPressed)
         {
             moveInput = -1; // Move left when only A or Left Arrow is pressed
        }
        else if (dPressed || rightArrowPressed)
         {
            moveInput = 1; // Move right when only D or Right Arrow is pressed
        }

        // Apply movement or stop sliding
         if (moveInput == 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y); // Stop horizontal movement      to prevent sliding
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y); // Move     player
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(Mathf.Sign(moveInput), 1, 1); // Flip     character
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        isGrounded = false;
        coyoteTimeCounter = 0f;
    }

    void UpdateAnimations()
    {
         anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x));
         anim.SetBool("isJumping", !isGrounded && coyoteTimeCounter <= 0);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") &&     collision.contacts[0].normal.y > 0.5f)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;

            if (jumpHeld)
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            coyoteTimeCounter = 0f; // Reset coyote time when leaving the ground
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
     {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(groundCheck.position, checkRadius);
    }
}


GetAxis applies a smoothing to input value, referred to as Sensitivity in the Input Manager, so the value will gradually change.

Sensitivity: Speed in units per second that the axis will move toward the target value. This is for digital devices only.

If you do not want this smoothing, you can use GetAxisRaw instead, or modify the Sensitivity value in the Input Manager.
float moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

